Save a Worksheet as an Object Attribute
I have an Employee class with properties Name and Worksheet for the purpose of compiling Employees Overtime sheets. The following code iterates through a folder, creates an Employee and adds it to a Dictionary. My problem is that once we're out of the Loop, the Worksheet becomes a generic Object, so I can't do any operation on it!
Sub ImportEmployeeFilesTest()
    Dim FolderPath As String
    Dim FileName As String
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim employee As EmployeeObject
    Dim EmployeesDict As Object
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    
    FolderPath = "C:\Users\0000\Desktop\VSCode\data\"
    FileName = Dir(FolderPath & "*_PunchClock.xlsm")
    
    Set EmployeesDict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    Do While FileName <> ""
        Set wb = Workbooks.Open(FolderPath & FileName)
        
        Set employee = New EmployeeObject

        employee.SetWorksheet wb.Sheets(1)
        EmployeesDict.Add employee.Name, employee
        
        MsgBox TypeName(EmployeesDict(employee.Name).EmployeeWorksheet) ' This prints Worksheet
    
        wb.Close False
        FileName = Dir
    Loop
    MsgBox TypeName(EmployeesDict("Spiderman").EmployeeWorksheet) ' This prints Object
        
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub

EmployeeObject.cls
Option Explicit

Public Name As String
Public EmployeeWorksheet As Worksheet

Private Sub Class_Initialize()

End Sub

Public Sub SetWorksheet(ws As Worksheet)
    Set EmployeeWorksheet = ws
    Me.SetName
End Sub

Public Sub SetName()
    If Not EmployeeWorksheet Is Nothing Then
        Me.Name = EmployeeWorksheet.Range("A2").Value
    Else
        Err.Raise vbObjectError + 1000, "Employee.SetName", "Worksheet is not set!"
    End If
End Sub

I have no idea why this happens and couldn't find anyone with the same problem on forums! I have tried using a Collection instead of Dictionary, but I get the same exact results... Please Help!

What's your end goal? Note that you can't do any operation anyway because wb is closed.

Manage the Overtime Sheets of 20+ Employees in a Master Sheet in which I'll eventually be able to filter in Employees by selecting their name on the left and compare their stats, etc. Indeed I notice that it works if I don't close WB, but I'll have 20 opened files I can't work with that!

Tough luck, unfortunately. A Worksheet can't exist without a parent Workbook. You can't close wb and still expect to work with one of its sheets. One option might be to combine the relevant sheets into a new workbook, if you must refer to a Worksheet.

Anyhow, as states above you cannot use a variable keeping a closed workbook. It does  not exist in memory, anymore.  In order to be reused, you need to keep somewhere the WB full name, not the object itself. Then, open the workbook and set it as object AFTER THAT... That object points to memory and not existing there, it cannot be reused.

PowerQuery seems like the better approach.

This is due to closing wb, not due to using a Dictionary or Collection. A Worksheet can't exist without a parent Workbook.
A simple example:
Sub Test()
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Set wb = Workbooks.Add
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = wb.Worksheets(1)
    Debug.Print TypeName(ws) ' Worksheet
    
    wb.Close False
    Debug.Print TypeName(ws) ' Object
End Sub

